# Ubuntu One Dropbox Conflict

Tags: ubuntu-one, dropbox

I am using 11.10 and have been using Dropbox on my various PCs (Windows and Ubuntu) for a long time. 
I decided to see what Ubuntu One was about and loaded it on all my PCs. It started to amend my files in Dropbox (even though they were not being synced by U1) by adding `.u1conflict` to any that I tried to save in the Dropbox folder. This has made my Dropbox folder unworkable. I have removed U1 from all my PCs but the Dropbox folder continues to add the suffix.

Answer (score 1):

"After using Ubuntu One and Dropbox for a while I conclude that Dropbox is a stable and reliable product that can largely be ignored once setup. For me this is really important. I choose to use Linux because it is a great operating system: simple to install and simple to use. Any service I use (whether it’s free or not) must perform as expected and improve my productivity. In a nutshell, Dropbox does this for me and Ubuntu One does not. Ubuntu One is unreliable and frustrating to use. This could be forgiven had Canonical decided not to market it as a fully functioning and complete service. With this in mind cost really doesn’t come into the equation. Yes, Dropbox can cost you more but then as the old adage goes you usually get what you pay for. Accordingly, I recommend Dropbox". ~Martin Webster

I agree and add if you want to keep dropbox you need to remove .dropbox and .dropbox-dist from your /home folder. Remove --purge and reinstall dropbox application.